# How can I embed an iframe correctly with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I embed an iframe using JavaScript, that's being displayed where the code's being added? The code below displays the iframe ONLY above the footer, no matter where I add the code, whether it's in the header or the body.

```
var iframe_tag = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://wikipedia.com");
iframe_tag.style.width = "100%";
iframe_tag.style.height = "480px";
document.body.appendChild(iframe_tag);
```

I know there are simpler ways to show an iframe, but I can only use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.body.appendChild` it is identical to just writing in the new html at the bottom, or literly appending the element to the bottom
This means that regardless of where the script is, it will always do this
instead you should append to a predefined div (`<div id="iframecontainer"> </div>`)

```
let container = document.getElementById("iframecontainer");
container.appendChild(iframe_tag);
```

minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.src = "https://wikipedia.com/";
            window.onload = () => {
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html
```

In my opinion you should, instead of creating an appending an element, just set the src of a pre-existing iframe (`<iframe id="iframe"> </iframe>`)

```
let iframe_tag = document.getElementById("iframe");
iframe.src = "https://wikipedia.com";
```

minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe"> </iframe>
        <script>
            let iframe;
            window.onload = () => {
                iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
                iframe.src = "https://www.wikipedia.com/";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html
```

Comment: I see, and how exactly should I write the code in this case? Thanks

Comment: @LucianBarligea I'd recommend 2nd but whatever you feel like

Comment: Unfortunately neither seem to work. Thanks anyway

Comment: there is a chance wikipedia doesn't let itself be shown in an iframe which might be the issue
both of these potential sollutions should be the equivilant of setting the src in the iframe in pure html, so I can quickly see if that works @Luciche

Comment: It seems to have worked so I added minimal examples in html which you can steal from ;D
@Luciche

Comment: The thing is that I'm putting the JS code into a script like this `<script src="https://dummysite.com/js"></script>`  and then I add this script to another site, and it doesn't work. 
The reason I'm complicating this is that I want to add a backlink above the iFrame, so it's outside the iFrame.